# Conditional sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, array-formulas, vba

I need a quick macro/formula. I have two columns:

```
          A   |   B
              |    
       |  10  |   9  |
       |  11  |      |
       |  8   |   10 |
       |     N/A     |
       |  4   |      |
       |  7   |   8  |

total  |  40  |   27 |
```

Now I want to add a sum to a column that adds up all the values in column A BUT replaces that value with the value in column B if it exists.

So I would expect the sum to end up being 9 + 11 + 10 + 4 + 8 = 42

I'm not entirely sure about the power of Excel's calculations or how to go about performing a for loop within a formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are MANY ways to do this, but I would do it as two sums added together....

Assuming you had the data you supplied in your question in cells A1 to B6, your formula could look as follows:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B6,"",A1:A6)+SUM(B1:B6)
```

In essence, you're saying:

1. Sum A1:A6 anywhere B1:B6 is blank

PLUS

1. Sum B1:B6

Hope this makes sense and helps!

Comment: +1; cuter than my answer especially for a basic Excel user - arrays are arcane.

Comment: Through absolutely no fault of yours, this answer ended up not working out of the box. It turns out that in some of the rows, the two columns cells were merged and had "N/A" in them, which tripped over on the equality check for "". My fault for not spotting that and adding it to the question sooner.

Comment: Scratch that, I just tried it again because I wasn't convinced I had it right, and it worked perfectly, I must have made a mistake the first time! apologies.

Comment: Very nice solution - appropriate for the task and the level of expertise of the user.

Answer (score 3):

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(B1:B5),B1:B5,A1:A5))
```

will do this. Note that the formula is an *array formula* though; once you've finished entering it in a cell, press Ctrl + Shift + Return, rather than Return. That tells Excel that the formula is an array type.

I've set this up for 5 rows; just extend as you need.

Comment: On further review, taking your advice about the danger of someone editing the cell and forgetting to set it to an array formula again (I won't be the one editing the spreadsheet). so I'll use another answer.

Answer (score 2):

One of many other possibilities could be a helper column containing:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B3),A3,B3)
```

copied down (and up, if necessary!)

Not necessarily *better* than many alternatives but perhaps easier to see 'what is going on' and =IF may already be familiar.

Comment: +1 as this is the easiest to maintain answer. My solution is vulnerable to someone editing the cell and forgetting to declare as an array by pressing Ctrl + Shift + Return.